# A permutation and combination question with too many cases

Tags: permutations, combinations

I know I shouldn't be asking homework questions but I tried. 
I am given 15 records (the kind you can play on a gramophone) which have one song on either side of the record (called the A and B sides). I wish to play this song in a loop (i.e. the starting song does not matter). How many different loops can I create if:
Every consecutive song must be from a different record?

There are too many cases to consider when I start picking the fourth song onwards. I can't think of an insertion method or a complement method. Is there an easy method for this?

Comment: It isn't 15! x 2^15. Thats the most common answer my friends gave me.

Comment: So you mean you will play each of the 15 records exactly once?

Comment: @MattiP. probably twice. Each of the 30 song should be played once. (I might be not interpreting correctly)

Comment: you must play 30 songs so technically is playing each record twice , once on each side.

Comment: In that case, one approach is to first put the records in order. There you get $15!$ cases. Then, for each record, you can choose one of two sides. So you get $2^{15}$ after that. For the second time around (the second round, 15 records) you know which side to play because you have already played the other side, but you can still reorder the records. In this case you get additional $15!$ cases. So I would guess the answer is $(15!)^2 \times 2^{15}$.

Comment: @MattiP. You failed to count the case where you play the A song from record 1, then the A song from record 2, then the B song from record 1.

Comment: So there are no restrictions to which song to play, as long as the song has not been played before? In that case, there are 30 songs, so $30!$ ...

Comment: @MattiP. No, the restriction is that the **record** cannot be consequitve. So, you cannot play song A and B from record 1 one after the other.

Comment: @MattiP. This condition is clearly written down by the OP, he said, I quote: "*Every consecutive song must be from a different record*"

Comment: For your first answer of the additional 15!. The problem with that is you aren't considering that it might be 1 A 1B 2A 2B which is included in that answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

This is a *derangement problem*. It is the same as the following: In how many ways can $15$ couples be seated at a round table (no strict $\ldots mfmfmfmf\ldots$ requirement) such that no couple sits next to each other? I'm afraid it has to be solved by setting up an inclusion/exclusion process.

Setting this process up (whereby loops differing only by a rotation are regarded as the same) leads to the formula
$$a(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\> {n\choose k}2^k (2n-1-k)!\ ,$$
giving  the numbers
$$\bigl(a(n)\bigr)_{n\geq2}=(2, 32, 1488, 112512, 12771840, 2036229120, 434469611520,\ldots)\ .$$
This is sequence [A129348](http://oeis.org/A129348) at OEIS. They say there the $a(n)$ count the Hamiltonian cycles of the cocktail party graph. At OEIS one may also find a recursion and asymptotics for the $a(n)$.